# TextMate \cite syntax highlighting

Tags: citing, textmate, syntax-checker

When I open a LaTeX document in TextMate, the syntax highlighting makes the part in braces in any cite command colored red, as if there is an error:

`\cite{why-is-this-red}`

Is there an easy way to avoid this?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's “an error”, for me it's like pink, it's just nice to have clear highlighting (it does stand out); I guess you could change the color in the theme you use to give you any color you wish.